# ASP.NET not showing any error, but unable to insert data into database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Under this I am trying to save the cart items chosen by the user into the database, for that I have initially selected the chosen items through `Request.Query` method now after that I have called those values and formed an `SaveCartDetail` function in which I have performed insert command into the database,the asp.net shows no error but there is no change in my table the name of my table is cart.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;

    dt.Columns.Add("sno");
    dt.Columns.Add("itemname");
    dt.Columns.Add("quantity");
    dt.Columns.Add("price");
    dt.Columns.Add("totalprice");
    dt.Columns.Add("image");

    if (Request.QueryString["itemname"] != null)
    {
        if (Session["Buyitems"] == null)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["online food orderingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            scon.Open();

            String myquery = "select * from food_items where item_name=@items_name";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myquery, scon);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("items_name", Request.QueryString["itemname"].ToString());

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            dr["sno"] = 1;

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dr["itemname"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["item_name"].ToString();
                dr["image"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
                dr["price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["price"].ToString();
                int price = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["price"].ToString());
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["quantity"].ToString());
                int totalprice = price * quantity; 
                dr["quantity"] = Request.QueryString["quantity"];

                dr["totalprice"] = totalprice;

                SaveCartDetail(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["item_name"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["quantity"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["price"].ToString(), totalprice.ToString());
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                Session["buyitems"] = dt;

                GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text = "Total Amount";
                GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[5].Text = grandtotal().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void SaveCartDetail(String itemname, String quantity, String price, String totalprice)
{
    String query = "insert into cart(item_name, quantity, price, totalprice, username) values ('" + itemname + "','" + quantity + "','" + price + "','" + totalprice + "','" + Session["username"].ToString() + "')";

    SqlConnection scon1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["online food orderingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    scon1.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, scon1);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    scon1.Close();

    Response.Write("Items saved in cart");
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). **WHY** are you using parameters on your first `SqlCommand` running the `SELECT` - but the `INSERT` command is still horrible string concatenation?? Use parameters **ALWAYS** - no exceptions!

Comment: I noticed that code is fetching the data from food_item table based on item name (pulled from querystring param) and then binding it to DataGrid. Does that functionality work and foot items displaying in grid? If if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) is false then SaveCartDetail will not be executed

Comment: If `SaveCartDetail` called? Does it have the data you expect? Use debugging to step through your code and confirm it is doing what you expect.